# How to get Remote Processes on Windows 2003 with cpu percentage

Tags: remote, windows, task-manager

I have a production server with it's cpu's running excessively high.  Except in critical circumstances nobody is allowed to logon to servers during non maintenance times.  I am looking for an application I can use to look at the processes on the remote server which **include** CPU % usage.  An application like ***top***.   Windows native tasklist.exe doesn't show percentage, nor does sysinternals pslist.exe.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually pslist -s does show percentages. ("Task Manager mode").

pslist -s \\computername

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx

Comment: Have no idea how I missed that.  I swear I tried that switch.  Thank you.